# How to access List<> using c:forEach?

Tags: jsp, arraylist, jstl, el

In my 1st servlet where i generate List is as follows

```
List<Image> imageId = imageDAO.listNames(image);

request.setAttribute("imageId", imageId);

//Redirect it to home page
request.getRequestDispatcher("/webplugin/jsp/profile/photos.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

which gets list of `imageId` to be displayed in JSP with help of `c:forEach`

```
<c:forEach items="${imageId}" var="image">
    <img src="Photos/${image.photoid}">
</c:forEach>
```

I have a Image bean class which has photoid as its properties

in second servlet which is mapped to `Photos` url-pattern i bring each photo.

Problem:

1. I am getting same image iterated over no of times which is equal to number of items in `imageId` list . Suppose imageId has five imageid's in its List then the same image is showed in my JSP for five times. How to retreive each `id` from it?

EDIT: This is my imageDAO.listNames() method to get photoid is there problem while retreiving images and putting it in `List<Image>`

```
public List<Image> listNames(Image image) throws IllegalArgumentException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;
    Database database = new Database();
    List<Image> list = new ArrayList<Image>();

    try {

        connection = database.openConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_GET_PHOTOID);                  
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, image.getUserid());
        resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while(resultset.next()) {
            image.setPhotoid(resultset.getString(1));
            list.add(image);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new SQLException(e);
    } finally {
        close(connection, preparedStatement, resultset);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that the list returned from your DAO has the correct IDs in it?

Comment: The code seems fine. In the first servlet, check that the 5 elements of the list contain a different photoid. Check the generated HTML to verify that the src attributes of the img tags are different and match the photoids of the list. Then check that the second servlet doesn't have a bug which would make it return always the same image. And finally check that the 5 images it returns are indeed different images.

Comment: Actually I tested this with input text box to print which id is being returned and it showed only one photoid but it iterated correctly for five times because that user had five photo in the database.

Comment: Updated my question with imageDAO.listNames() method. Is there problem in my imageDAO.listNames() method while retreiving photoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over the result set, you are setting the photo id of the **same image object** over and over again ... and then re-inserting the same object to the list multiple times.

**Update:** simply put, your logical model in that method is flawed. You don't need the image parameter. Something like this should work (the emphasis is on creating a new Image object in each iteration):

```
List<Image> list = new ArrayList<Image>();
try {
    ...
    while(resultset.next()) {
        Image image = new Image ();
        image.setPhotoid(resultset.getString(1));
        list.add(image);
```

and then your list will have several distinct objects.

Comment: Then how should it be like? Can you give me an some code? It might be helpful.